# Spring security: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored.

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to configure spring security on my simple app, but I keep getting this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
```

I have seen other similar posts, but could not figure out why I am getting this error. I don't seems to have duplicate security:http namespace configured.

Here goes my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">

<display-name>sampler</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:**/sampler-context.xml
        classpath:**/sampler-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sampler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sampler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring security config:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Add Authentication Manager -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" password="test"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- This would add login screen -->
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
</http>
```

Its just a simple login functionality that I wanted to provide as of now. Any help around this issue would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the regex of classpath in the context-param.

```
<param-value>
    classpath:**/sampler-context.xml
    classpath:**/sampler-security.xml
</param-value>
```

Changing it to

```
    <param-value>
        classpath*:sampler-context.xml
        classpath*:sampler-security.xml
    </param-value>
```

solves this problem.